# How can i compare two linear regressions in R that do not have the same response variable?

Tags: r, regression, anova

I have two models. One is a simple linear model and the second model is based on randomly shuffled values of the same model as used for the first one. I would like to prove that the slope of the first model is different from a slope that would result from randomly shuffled values. How can I achieve this? The function `anova()` does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by *"that do not have the same response variable"*, is the response the shuffled variable?

Comment: I shuffled both, the dependent and independent variable. R is now putting back an error "..because response differs from model 1" when i use anova()

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: The randomly shuffled data should have a slope that is not significantly different from 0. That is exactly what the "t value" in the `summary()` function is testing. Shuffling the data is telling you more about the algorithm you used for shuffling than it is about the significance of the slope value in the original regression.